# Twisted module in kivy

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, kivy

I am trying to make a server & client program using python & kivy...While using twisted module in code i am getting a error..
Code:-

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)


def main():

    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = Echo
    reactor.listenTCP(8000,factory)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After running this code in python shell.. i am getting a error which is shown below

Error:-

> from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol ImportError: No module
>   named twisted.internet

How can i overcome this import error..???

Comment: You don't have the twisted module you need to install it first https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted

Comment: After installing twisted module..i am still getting a error while running the same code...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Codes\simpleserver.py", line 4, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    _checkRequirements()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\__init__.py", line 37, in _checkRequirements
    raise ImportError(required + ": no module named zope.interface.")
ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zope.interface.

Comment: twisted for windows requires `zope.interface` http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads. You need to install it too.